Will a Modified Maxwellian Demon Experiment Using Charged Particles Be Able to Recycle Heat?

(If necessary this experiment can be conducted in an environment where gravity is negligible to avoid gravitational effects.)
Two adjacent containers are filled with a homogenous gas composed of charged particles at a high temperature. These isolated containers initially have the same macroscopic properties, meaning they are in a state of thermodynamic equilibrium. A nano-scale tunnel, designed to prevent interference to the particle sorting mechanism by the rest of the system by randomly channelling particles one at a time, connects the two containers. At the middle section of this tunnel, a detection coil is wounded around to detect the electromagnetic field generated by a particle’s motion.
As a random charged particle moves along the tunnel, it creates a detectable magnetic field due to its motion which will induce an EMF (proportional to its velocity) on the primary coil (P1) driving an electric current through a secondary coil (S1) (located at an arbitrary distance further along the tunnel) which in turn will act as an electromagnet to attract a closely positioned nano-scale trapdoor (T1) made of slim steel foil (only if the particle's velocity is above the arbitrary selection threshold measured by the intensity of the EMF induced on the detection coil) to open the tunnel in time to allow the particle's escape to the other container. Thus the trap door is controlled by a mechanism sensitive to the velocities of the particles through the tunnel. After the particle has passed through to the other container the trap door snaps shut completing the selection of the high-energy particle.
In essence, the device functions with synchronized precision requiring only a minuscule amount of energy. When a fast-moving particle from the first container approaches, the device activates the door, allowing the particle to pass into the second container.
A second tunnel similar to the first one but located far enough (to avoid interference with the first tunnel) also connects the two containers. The only difference is that; this tunnel is designed to allow low-energy particles in the opposite direction, from the second container to the first. So the detection coil will still be in the middle of the tunnel but the trap door will be nearer to the first container, so the particle coming from the second container will pass the detection coil before the trap door. The detection coil (P2), trap door actuation coil (S2), and trap door (T2) specs are designed to lower the velocity selection threshold so that the average velocity of particles allowed through the trap door will be lower.
This selective transfer of particles based on their velocities causes the second container to gradually warm up as it accumulates faster particles and loses slower particles, while the first container cools down as it loses faster particles and accumulates slower ones. Despite the containers starting at the same temperature, a temperature gradient is created without external work or energy input, as the energy used by the filtering device is itself extracted from the kinetic energy of the particles in the composite system.
In this experiment, particles lose a certain amount of energy due to the detection-selection mechanism as it draws no external power but uses electromagnetically inducted energy from moving charged particles. But as the mechanism operates on highly efficient circuitry, particles only lose a small amount of energy thus particles slowing down only a little bit.
Furthermore, the efficiency of the mechanism can significantly be increased by using heavier particles or raising the initial temperature level. Consequently, it is reasonable to assume the amount of energy needed for the detection-selection process hence, the increase of the entropy is minimal compared to the decrease of the average entropy per particle sorted.
It is true that there is a certain energy cost due to the operation of the selection process because while certain particles are selected, certain more are rejected. Both the rejected and selected particles cost energy while the temperature increase is only due to selected particles. And the more acute the selection threshold becomes, the more acute the energy consumption becomes. However, as long as the selection and elimination process operates on a marginal energy cost relative to the resulting energy separation by the process, the total entropy still decreases.
Relation to the Second Law of Thermodynamics:
Traditionally, the second law states that heat cannot spontaneously flow from a cooler to a warmer region without external work. However, in this thought experiment, heat effectively flows from the cooler first container to the warmer second container (They were initially at the thermodynamic equilibrium conditions) due to the active filtering of particles, challenging the traditional interpretation of the second law.
But the important thing is this only proves that: "heat can be transferred between separate systems whatever their temperature is without external work as long as particles comprising the systems have different energies", but not that "the total energy of the system can be increased".
Since the current technologies have reached the limit of nano-scale manufacturing design it might be possible to fabricate this contraption using a such small form factor. However, at such small scales, substantial inter-molecular and quantum effects can affect the trap door operation.
John Earman and John D. Norton have argued that Szilárd and Landauer's explanations of Maxwell's demon begin by assuming that the second law of thermodynamics cannot be violated by the daemon, and derive further properties of the demon from this assumption, including the necessity of consuming energy when erasing information, etc. It would therefore be circular to invoke these derived properties to defend the second law from the demonic argument. That also shows that "second law could not be violated proofs" essentially circular self-proving due assumption that any device must adhere to the second law rather than being any inherent theoretical proof.
The key is that macroscopic violations of the second law are experimentally possible despite natural occurrences of such phenomena being extremely rare in nature. The law is probabilistic, not absolute or fundamental. And as a result, hypothetically we can design macroscopic devices or designs to circumvent the second law in isolated systems. We are not yet practically able to because by nature such violations are rare at the macroscopic level and we need to design high-efficiency devices at the microscopic level to harness entropy decrease at the macroscopic level which is extremely difficult using current technologies, but theoretically possible. So it is important to understand that the second law presents a statistical improbability but not a theoretical impossibility. So while entropy by nature tends to increase, we can theoretically devise ways to reverse that in controlled environments.
The experiment is not about disproving the second law (the second law of thermodynamics will exist in its pure statistical form and as an empirical observation in the wild), but just proving that the second law of thermodynamics is a statistical probability only, not a theoretical ultimatum.
Summary and probable conclusions of the experiment
◆ A and B are two isolated containers hosting charged homogenous gas particles at temperature T. Both containers are initially at thermodynamic equilibrium within each system and with each other.
◆ P1 and P2 are primary coils designed to detect incoming particles from containers A and B respectively.
◆ When a charged particle travels through P1 or P2, an electro-motive force will be induced upon them, which in turn will drive a current through the S1 or S2 secondary coils respectively.
◆ If the electric currents are sufficient S1 and S2 will act as electro-magnets that actuate trap doors T1 and T2 respectively in time to allow respective particles to escape into the corresponding containers.
◆ P1, S1 and T1 specs are chosen to be different from P2, S2 and T2 such that the first triplet will allow particles with higher velocity on average while the second triplet will allow particles with a relatively lower average velocity.
◆ The entire mechanism is analogous to a real-world version of Maxwell’s demon thus decreasing the total entropy of the system (Assuming Entropy decrease due to the detection and sorting mechanism will exceed the entropy increase caused by its energy consumption).
◆ The particle sorting mechanism will be able to gradually create a macroscopic net entropy difference between the two containers only using a small portion of the particles' kinetic energies (without using any energy external to the composite system)(and used energy shall be fed back into the composite system as low-grade heat as the sorting mechanism is internal to the isolated system) and hence will be able to circumvent (but not exceed because each cycle will still be within the Carnot limit) the Carnot limit of a perfect heat engine. Thus, intelligent beings/complex mechanisms will be able to harness the energy of the Universe infinite times using such devisings, theoretically as long as there exist particles of non-zero motility in close proximities to each other (close enough for frequent random collisions which result in a  Maxwell-Boltzmann velocity distribution). Thus reversing the heat death of the universe indeed. (Of course, unless dark energy will eventually surpass any cohesion forces to pull particles so far away from each other that no collisions are possible anymore.)
◆ However, this cycle of decreasing and increasing entropy (sorting out particles and then using the resulting entropy gradient between the two containers for macroscopic work and then sorting out particles again) causes low-grade heat production, thereby reducing the velocity range of particles thus effectively reducing the efficiency of the sorting mechanism. The system will tend to approach a microscopically uniform state of energy where every particle within the composite system becomes of nearly the same velocity/energy thus gradually decreasing the practical efficiency of the system, as a consequence, the sorting mechanism can (practically) entirely cease to be profitable and tend to act only as an entropy increasing mechanism. That is unless the composite system's inherent tendency towards  Maxwell-Boltzmann distribution due to random particle collisions is sufficient to counter the particles' velocity loss due to the sorting mechanism, or there is a randomising input (driving up the velocity difference between particles) that is external (not really, but effectively) to the system like quantum fluctuations (if quantum fluctuations are truly random, meaning not decided by the already existing conditions of the composite system).
Questions

Are my conclusions regarding the experiment and the second law of thermodynamics correct?

Can this experiment be done practically if carefully designed using currently available technologies? Or is this theoretically possible but we do not yet have the technology advanced enough?

Can this type of device effectively be used to decrease entropy, reverting thermodynamic equilibrium?


If this experiment is not doable please explain why it is so.

Sorry for this post being so long, but I didn't know how else to present this question.

This seems reminiscent of the Feynman ratchet. Where have you analyzed the thermal fluctuations of the trap door and how they affect particle transfer? If the gating device is externally cooled to eliminate thermal fluctuations, the device may essentially act as an externally powered heat pump.

@Chemomechanics Do You think thermal noise disrupts the function of the trapdoor?  But the trap door can be made large enough and tunnel long enough.

The size of the tunnel and trapdoor does not matter, the interaction with the particles will make it to eventually reach thermodynamic equilibrium with the gases and stop working as you expect, letting particles move in both directions (by randomly opening and letting particles of the "wrong" side to cross). Not too different than the Feynman ratchet mentioned in one of the comments.
Any interactions however weak, between the sensor and the gas will end up in reaching thermodynamic equilibrium between them. And at that point the device will stop working as you expect due to the thermal fluctuations.
